# When dealing with sums of independent random variables is this correct?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

So I have this problem that says $W,X,Y$, and $Z$ are all independent random variables and all have standard normal distribution. Find $P(W+X>Y+Z+1)$. Now I know that $W+X-Y-Z$ will also be independent and standard normal distribution, however what I'm confused about is this:

I know that if I make $W$ and $X$ standard normal I could say to let $U=W+X$ and then $U\sim N(\mu_W +\mu_X , \sigma^2_W +\sigma^2_X)$.

Now lets say I want to find $P(W+X-Y-Z>1)$ .

How would I normalize that (is that the correct verbage)? Would I say to let $V=W+X-Y-Z$ and then $V\sim N\left(\mu_W +\mu_X-\mu_Y-\mu_z , \sigma^2_W +\sigma^2_X-\sigma^2_Y-\sigma^2_Z\right)$?

Comment: Kyle, this is minor but when you say, "Now I know that $W+X-Y-Z$ will also be independent", I'm not sure what you are trying to say here but statements about independence must involve the comparison of at least two random variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are fairly close, but the random variable $W+X-Y-Z$ has variance $\sigma_W^2 +\sigma_X^2+\sigma_Y^2+\sigma_Z^2$ (plus signs only).

In general if $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n$ are **independent** normal with means $\mu_i$ and variances $\sigma_i^2$, and $a_1,a_2,\dots, a_n$ are any constants, then $\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i$ is **normally distributed**, with mean $\sum_1^n a_i\mu_i$ and variance $\sum_1^n a_i^2 \sigma_i^2$.

Note the squaring of the $a_i$. In your case, the $a_i$ are always $1$ or $-1$, so their squares are $1$.

Comment: How come with the variance were adding them all vs what I had?

Comment: @Kyle: Well, one could *prove* it, by going back to the formula for variance. But informally, think of two random variables $X$ and $Y$, and their difference $X-Y$. Both the wiggliness of $X$ and the wiggliness of $Y$ contribute to the wiggliness of $X-Y$. Take for example the case where $X$ and $Y$ have equal variance. Could $X-Y$ have variance $0$? That would mean totally predictable, constant!. And if the variance of $Y$ is bigger than the variance of $X$, could the variance of $X-Y$ be *negative*? Impossible, variance is never negative.